# Making KSQLDB cluster highly available for pull queries

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a 2 node KSQLDB 0.26 cluster running on GKE. Both run okay independently but they're not set up properly for high availability and I cannot figure out why.
When I try to get the introspective cluster status from the  `/clusterStatus` endpoint, the `hostAlive` value is always `false` for one of the servers. This is while there is a `SELECT * FROM X AS SELECT` query running.
When I try to pull the query, I get this output:

> {"@type":"statement_error","error_code":40001,"message":"Error
> starting pull query: Unable to execute pull query. [Partition 0 failed
> to find valid host. Hosts scanned: [ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected
> because Host is not alive as of time 1656932189568,Lag information is
> not present for host., ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected because Lag
> information is not present for host.], Partition 1 failed to find
> valid host. Hosts scanned: [ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected because Lag
> information is not present for host., ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected
> because Host is not alive as of time 1656932189568,Lag information is
> not present for host.], Partition 2 failed to find valid host. Hosts
> scanned: [ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected because Host is not alive as
> of time 1656932189568,Lag information is not present for host.,
> ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected because Lag information is not present
> for host.], Partition 3 failed to find valid host. Hosts scanned:
> [ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected because Lag information is not present
> for host., ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected because Host is not alive as
> of time 1656932189568,Lag information is not present for host.],
> Partition 4 failed to find valid host. Hosts scanned: [ksqldb-2:8099
> was not selected because Host is not alive as of time
> 1656932189568,Lag information is not present for host., ksqldb-1:8099
> was not selected because Lag information is not present for host.],
> Partition 5 failed to find valid host. Hosts scanned: [ksqldb-1:8099
> was not selected because Lag information is not present for host.,
> ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected because Host is not alive as of time
> 1656932189568,Lag information is not present for host.], Partition 6
> failed to find valid host. Hosts scanned: [ksqldb-2:8099 was not
> selected because Host is not alive as of time 1656932189568,Lag
> information is not present for host., ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected
> because Lag information is not present for host.], Partition 7 failed
> to find valid host. Hosts scanned: [ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected
> because Lag information is not present for host., ksqldb-2:8099 was
> not selected because Host is not alive as of time 1656932189568,Lag
> information is not present for host.], Partition 8 failed to find
> valid host. Hosts scanned: [ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected because
> Host is not alive as of time 1656932189568,Lag information is not
> present for host., ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected because Lag
> information is not present for host.], Partition 9 failed to find
> valid host. Hosts scanned: [ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected because Lag
> information is not present for host., ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected
> because Host is not alive as of time 1656932189568,Lag information is
> not present for host.], Partition 10 failed to find valid host. Hosts
> scanned: [ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected because Host is not alive as
> of time 1656932189568,Lag information is not present for host.,
> ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected because Lag information is not present
> for host.], Partition 11 failed to find valid host. Hosts scanned:
> [ksqldb-1:8099 was not selected because Lag information is not present
> for host., ksqldb-2:8099 was not selected because Host is not alive as
> of time 1656932189568,Lag information is not present for
> host.]]\nStatement: select * from
> DOMAIN_TIER_TABLE;","statementText":"select * from
> DOMAIN_TIER_TABLE;","entities":[]}

I'm using the Docker image with a UDF loaded and HTTP Basic auth on KSQL.
I think these are the relevant KSQL env vars in my kubernetes deployment manifest:

```
- name: KSQL_LISTENERS          
  value: http://0.0.0.0:8089
- name: KSQL_KSQL_INTERNAL_LISTENER
  value: "http://0.0.0.0:8099"
- name: KSQL_KSQL_ADVERTISED_LISTENER
  value: "http://ksqldb-1:8099"
- name: KSQL_KSQL_STREAMS_NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS
  value: "1"
- name: KSQL_KSQL_QUERY_PULL_ENABLE_STANDBY_READS
  value: "true"
- name: KSQL_KSQL_HEARTBEAT_ENABLE
  value: "true" 
- name: KSQL_KSQL_LAG_REPORTING_ENABLE
  value: "true"
```

This is for one server. The other one will use ksqldb-2 as the hostname. This resolves to an IP address which I confirmed by getting a shell on the pods and checking with `printenv` to check if these variables were being passed. Everything looks as though they were. I have a service for each of the servers.
I have a feeling that I've set up my listeners incorrectly but I've tried so many different iterations of the listeners.

I am not used to asking questions on stackoverflow so I'm not so sure what else to provide, but I can provide anything required! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, securing KSQL using HTTP Basic auth causes high availability for pull queries to break. This is because the heartbeats sent for HA to be enabled return a 401. At the moment I do not see a way to pass authentication details with these heartbeats.

If you can leverage off of an NGINX ingress controller to pass oauth credentials, that would probably be best. In our case, however, the last jump between KSQL and NGINX does not support HTTP/2 which is required for some scopes within the Streams API that we need.